# Angular 2 share/change data got from HTTP service between components

Tags: http, angular, data-binding

I have to develop an Angular 2 application in which I have an HTTP service whose response is a JSON object like that:

```
plan = {ID: 'planID', installmentsNumber: 10, rate: 5}
```

I need these data to be shared between more components and every update to be caught by every component.

Which is the best way?

UPDATE (Nov 23, 2016)

I developed my app using Observable, like you can see in the plunk below:
https://plnkr.co/edit/0k0jr8KrJfFKeNkIV6So?p=info

Solved. Thanks to all.

Comment: You should rather read http://angular.io instead of focusing on the code. Understand the important patterns before playing with your choosen framework.

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Comment: @VassilisPits yes, I checked and I tried to develop my app using Observables, but I encountered other issues that I'll try to recap in the update of my question. Could you please check it?

Comment: Well I guess this will have to be a separate question @B.Ciervo. If this answer helped your or show you the way you should accept it, if not, not. In your new question I'll participate with an answer if I can. Play fair ;)

Comment: Ok, sorry I'm new to StackOverflow, I'll make a separate question ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `RxJs Observable` library for that matter.
As your questions is broad and you haven't shared a working example I propose to you to read the following blog articles:

**How to build Angular 2 apps using Observable Data Services**
http://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/
**Angular 2 HTTP Requests with Observables**
https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-http-requests-with-observables

I prefer `BehaviourSubject` because you can initialise it easily and set a default state.

Comment: I think that the first thing to mention before RxJs is that he needs a factory. How to synchronize with components is an other story. RxJs is very (very very very) handy, but a simple factory might do it.

Comment: @Maxime what do you mean `factory`. In angular2 there are no factories as in 1.x version. Did I misunderstood you?

Comment: No sorry it's me, I meant service!

Comment: But he just told on the question that he has a service already.